# Is it worth it to make web api async method?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, async-await, angular-promise

Angular $http methods return a promise. Therefore by nature it's already an async call to the web api..  Now the question is in what circumstance you wish to make your web api method to be async/await :

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string id)
{
     return await .......  ;
}
```

Comment: These are unrelated. You make the server async to improve utilization and scalability.

Answer (score 2):

If your method has asynchronous work to do, then it should be async.

As @l3arnon commented, async on the server and async on the client are completely different. Async on the client is all about remaining responsive to the end-user (not blocking the UI thread). Async on the server is all about scalability (not blocking thread pool threads).